# How To (wrapInner or wrapAll) Excluding first div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[image]

I want to wrap all the items below "name portlet-title" But, Should not include other items in "div class name portlet-title" below. where i tried following ways:

1) `$("div.item").wrapAll('<div class="portlet-body"></div>');`

it is effecting all item in page.

2) `$("div.list").wrapInner('<div class="portlet-body"></div>');`

it is including "div class name portlet-title"

i am not so good at jquery please help me out.

Comment: Your question is not understood. (below "name portlet-title"  ,  But, Should not include other items in "div class name portlet-title" below....???????????????)

Comment: yes it is div class, even both are div classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop so that you can group the items separately.

```
$('.list.portlet').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div.item').wrapAll('<div class="portlet-body"></div>')
})
```